# Redirect URL product to

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect in .htaccess about 300 links that changed their name such as:

**director/subdirector/productname** to **director/subdirector/new-words-productname**

In which **productname** is always beggining with the same letters: **TJ** 
and the rest of the productname is a combination of figures and letters.

The change consists only in adding the string "**new-words**".

I tried many methods, but it didn't work.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(director/subdirector)/([TJ][^.]+)$ /$1/new-words-$2
```

Comment: I applied the rule and here is the new link:

/director/subdirector/productname-TJ55CM5S?section=director&cat=subdirector&subcat=TJ55CM5S

Comment: Didn't you white in question that product name starts with letter T or J? Can you provide clear examples of old and new URLs?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. All the path remains the same. I just have to change the product name, which starts with a group of 2 letters: "TJ" and continues with a variable group of letters and figures. I have to add in front of "TJ" something like: "Electric-generator-" 

It also may be a problem with the rest of .htaccess code, which I tried to post in the comment, but it was completely messed up. I will post it anyway, maybe you can understand. And thank you very much.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?section=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3&item=$4&%1 [L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?section=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3&%1 [L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?section=$1&cat=$2&%1 [L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?section=$1&%1 [L,NC]

Comment: Your code is not readable from comments. Click on `edit` link below your question and provide this formatted code there.